# Adding a disabled game mode on a Phaser game

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm trying to add a *disabled* mode to a Phaser game. 
Basically this would not stop the game from moving forward, but would disable the user's output and display a gray overlay. I'm trying to make it work like `this.game.paused` works.

[Link to my example repo](https://github.com/gamedolphin/Masonry-JavaScript-Tetris-Clone) 
[Live Example](http://gamedolph.in/sample-page/masonry-tetris-clone/)

Comment: i think there is no phaser method or class to do it you just need to do it manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **game.input.enabled**

```
game.input.enabled = false;  //all input sources are ignored.
```

To disable just one type of input; for example, the Mouse, use

```
game.input.mouse.enabled = false;
```

a gray overlay should be added manually.